# install windows 7 from virtual box on Ubuntu, create virtual hard drive

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  installed on 128GB SSD drive. The home is on HDD. I am going to install Windows 7 from virtual box (VB). Is there any straightforward way to make a virtual hard disk file on SSD drive and tell the VB to install  Windows on that virtual hard disk file?
Or it is easier to make new partition on SSD drive and reinstall the Ubuntu, and also install Windows alongside or through VB.

**Update :**

It may be helpful for others that read it later to add some details of what I did

I used part of [this](https://www.tecmint.com/create-virtual-harddisk-volume-in-linux/) post to create a virtual hard disk using a file.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=VHD.img bs=1M count=1200
sudo mkfs -t ext4 VHD.img
```

I put this file in SSD drive and convert IMG file to VDI file using Oracle VirtualBox:

```
VBoxManage convertdd input.img output.vdi
```

If you wand to give this VDI file to VirtualBox, it give to a permission error, so you can change the permission of the file using

```
sudo chmod a+rwx VHD.vdi
```

That's all.

Comment: You want a full/dual install of Win 7 on your SSD?  The easiest way would be to burn a Win 7 ISO to a USB.  You do know that Win 7 is no longer supported and should use Win 10.  Win10 is available for free if you use google to find.  If need to use Win7, be best to use it in a VM, not installed on a drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

virtulbox installs an OS in a virtual disk file (.vdi). You don't need to make a partition. You can create or select this .vdi file when you create that virtual machine. You can surely store that .vdi file in the ssd drive if you can set the write permission.